# Detect width of objects in image

Tags: python, opencv

I have images like the following (these are the output of a UNET on the original image):

[image: example1], [image: example2], [image: example3]

I thought segmenting the original image was the difficult task, but I have been struggling with the following task:
for each image I have to compute the width of the green area in correspondence with the red one, as follows:

[image: distance1], [image: distance2], [image: distance3]

What I tried to do:

Detecting the edgs of the green area was straightforward. Then I found the lines in polar coordinates through the Hough Transform:

```
image = cv2.imread("../../../../example_1.png")
image[:, :, 2] = 0
canny = cv2.Canny(image, 150, 250, 3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(canny, cv2.HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC, np.pi/180, 20)
for line in lines:
    for x0, y0, x1, y1 in line:
        cv2.line(image, (x0,y0), (x1,y1), (255, 255, 255), 1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1).set_title("canny")
plt.imshow(canny, cmap = "gray")
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2).set_title("lines")
plt.imshow(image)
```

Which gives:

[image: cannyplushough]

As you can see there are many candidates lines (many false positives) and I'm struggling to keep the ones I need. Furthermore: How would you calculate width?

Using houghlines in polar coordinates I was able to retrieve the angle each line has with the origin of the axis, so to calculate width I should find a pair of parallel lines (same angle or almost same angle) with different distance from the origin. I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Thanks for helping

Comment: you could try minAreaRect to estimate the main-directions. Skeleton-algoritnhms might help, too. The general approach might be to find the medial axis. Or try distanceTransform and search for the maximum distance within the object, or the maximum of some "cluster" distance.

Comment: Use blob detection to isolate each region. Then get the area of each region.

Answer (score 2):

As @Micka suggested you can use `cv2.minAreaRect` to do this. To do this you can apply simple thresholding on the two red and green planes followed by contour estimation. Then the largest contours can be taken and the smallest rectangle by area can be found. Using its coordinates the height and width can be calculated and then their ratio. The code is

```
img = cv2.imread('red_green.png')
red = img[:, :, 2] # to segment out red area
green = img[:, :, 1] # to segment out green are
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(red, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(green, 5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, cnts1, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_, cnts2, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c1 = max(cnts1, key = cv2.contourArea)
c2 = max(cnts2, key = cv2.contourArea)
rect1 = cv2.minAreaRect(c1)
rect2 = cv2.minAreaRect(c2)
box1 = cv2.boxPoints(rect1)
box2 = cv2.boxPoints(rect2)
box1 = np.int0(box1)
box2 = np.int0(box2)
cv2.drawContours(img, [box1], 0, (0, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.drawContours(img, [box2], 0, (0, 255, 255), 2)
(p1, p2, p3, p4) = box1 # Unpacking tuple
h1 = (((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)**0.5) # calculating width by calculating distance
w1 = (((p2[0]-p3[0])**2 + (p2[1]-p3[1])**2)**0.5) # calculating height by calculating distance
(p1, p2, p3, p4) = box2 # Unpacking tuple
h2 = (((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)**0.5) # calculating width by calculating distance
w2 = (((p2[0]-p3[0])**2 + (p2[1]-p3[1])**2)**0.5) # calculating height by calculating distance
rofh = h2/h1
rofw = w2/w1
print("ratio of height = ", rofh, "and ratio by width = ", rofw)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The resulting image is

[image]